# If a seller sells to the highest bid of the three, what is the probability that the selling price is less than $160?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

> Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be random variables denoting $3$ independent bids for an item that is for sale. Suppose each $X_i$ ($i= 1, 2, 3$) is uniformly distributed on the interval $[100,200]$ (in dollars).  If the seller sells to the highest bid of the three, what is the probability that the selling price is less than $160?

I'm unsure how to setup this problem. Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the selling price is $\leq 160$ precisely when all three bids are $\leq 160$. Now use independence.

Comment: So I figured the distribution function to use here is f(x) = x-100/200 but I'm not sure what to do next!

Comment: Use independence. You want the probability that all three bids are $\leq 160$. This is the product of the individual probabilities since the $X_i$ are independent.

Comment: PS: @SuhailPrasathong The Cumulative Distribution Function for the uniform distribution is $F(x)=(x-100)/(200-100)\quad[100\leq x\leq 200]+1[x>200]$.

Comment: @SuhailPrasathong A generalization of the maximum and minimum to the kth smallest item is the notion of an (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) order statistic. You don't need it for this particular problem, (it is easy) but it is useful in general.